# Last uppercase word from String

Tags: php, regex

I want uppercase word from string

`WORDA - WORDB - WORDC - Failure occurring to be verified if a WORDD WORDE is linked to the failure.`

the expected output i want for above string is like this :

`WORDD WORDE`

Comment: OT: How idiotic that SO does not let you post "what have you tried?" as a comment any more. The OP might be new to the site, or shy about posting erroneous attempts, or...

Comment: Are you asking for the last 2 words?  Your question is unclear.  Please provide 3 different sample inputs and their expected results to give your question context / clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
<?php
$a= "WORDA - WORDB - WORDC - Failure occurring to be verified if a WORDD WORDE is linked to the failure.";
$b= '/([A-Z|\s\0-9]+)[a-z|\W\|0-9]*$/';
preg_match($b, $a, $c, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($c[1][0]);
?>
```